# Как создать автоматическое добавление id в миграциях laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Я хотел бы, чтобы у меня был автоматическое добавление id в бд. Использую postgresql.В миграциях прописываю следующее:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('anketas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
}
```

Но id  не добавляется.Подскажите,пожалуйста, как сделать

Comment: ну есть такая вещь: `$table->id();` и всё работает. По умолчанию при создании миграции через консоль ларавель прописывает данную строку

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно вам помочь)

```
public function up()
{  
  Schema::create('anketas', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id()->primary();
  }
}
```